# Как закрепить div в правом нижнем углу браузера в IE?

Tags: html

Для всех кроме IE работает такой css:

```
width:310px; 
height:35px; 
position:fixed; 
top:auto; 
bottom:0px; 
z-index:1000;  
display:block; 
overflow:hidden;
```

Но в IE не работает. Как закрепить div  в правом нижнем угле в IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*html (нужный DIV) {
position: absolute;
top: expression(document.getElementsByTagName(
`body`)[0].scrollTop + "px");
```

Может попробовать так?

Так же еще прописать

```
body
{
    background:url(about:blank);
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Чтобы блок не дергался.

Comment: Да,но оно фиксирует в правом верхнем углу, а не в нижнем

Comment: А что если top просто на 100% сместить?